# upload application video to server using afnetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, video, afnetworking

i will try to upload video using afnetworking.i will take one video in my project than upload in server.only i want to upload video in server.

here is my code

```
- (IBAction)uplosd:(id)sender {
      // name of the image
    NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample.mp4" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoURL]];
      // convert your image into data

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"];  // enter your url to upload

    // AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    // allocate AFHTTPManager
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager POST:urlString parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {  // POST DATA USING MULTIPART CONTENT TYPE
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData
                                    name:@"image"
                                fileName:@"video" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];   // add image to formData
        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[@"sdsd" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                    name:@"key1"];
         // add your other keys !!!

    } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);    // Get response from the server



    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);   // Gives Error

    }];

}
```

here sample.mp4 is video is stored in my project.pls help me

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: this one error is display Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: print `videoURL `. It is returning nil or not

Comment: @BhavinRamani videourl value is display null value

Comment: Try this: `NSString * videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"]; ` and print again.

Comment: output is  videourl=/var/mobile/Applications/A5D856A4-160F-4C6E-B21A-666069A514E0/videoupload.app/sample.mp4

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: this error display  JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Comment: I think you are getting wrong json format in response

Comment: please help i am new in ios

Comment: `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];`

Comment: your issue solved or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115920/discussion-between-dany-and-bhavin-ramani).

Comment: i think webapi side problem

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
            manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
     NSData *tempData = nil;

            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];



            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:strRequestUrl parameters:pdictParams constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                                 {

                                                     if (data)
                                                     {
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:tempData name:@"video_file" fileName:[path lastPathComponent] mimeType:@"video/mp4"];
          }
                                         } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        }];

            [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

                NSLog(@"Upload Progress %lld",totalBytesWritten*100/totalBytesExpectedToWrite);


     float fltProgress = (float)totalBytesWritten/(float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

                NSLog(@"%f",fltProgress);

            }];
            // [operation setInputStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strRequestUrl]]];
            [operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                [operation pause];
            }];
```

2)

```
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    [manager POST:strRequestUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"video" error:nil];
    } progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Comment: same problem occur

Comment: Check what you are getting in data variable.

Comment: Go to : Target -> "Build Phases" -> "copy bundle Resources" Then add that particular file here. If that file is already added , delete it and add it again.

Comment: output is videourl=/var/mobile/Applications/A5D856A4-160F-4C6E-B21A-666069A514E0/videoupload.app/sample.mp4

Comment: Now you will get data.

Comment: this error is display JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Comment: You are getting in response?

Comment: i got this response videoupload[8700:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1758dbb0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: Please check your request structure for webservice.

Comment: Just add required classes .

Comment: i will try after 5 minute i will tell you

Comment: @dany : the longest 5 minutes ever :D